# What could be the reason I'm getting the "ERR_SSL_UNRECOGNIZED_NAME_ALER" on my browser while the website works fine from other devices?

Tags: php, security, ssl, browser, web-hosting

I rehosted my website after it was down for a year with a new SSL. I can only assume im getting this error because i used the same computer to do it.
I have reset the SSL cache, deleted browsing history but the website just gives me errors such as stylesheet failed to load becasue of "ERR_SSL_UNRECOGNIZED_NAME_ALER". The website works fine from other devices but on the same pc, it still gives errros on other browsers. What could be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The device in question is likely using a different IP to access the site then the other devices. This might be due to the old IP address still being cached in the PC (did you try to reboot?) or even hard coded (did you check hosts file) or it might be an issue of IPv4 vs. IPv6, i.e. your PC accessing the site by IPv6 but the site is only properly setup with IPv4 - which is used by the other systems.

Caching the old IP might also be done by non-local name servers, i.e. you might have a specific name server setup on your PC, it might be a name server on the router or on the ISP. In these cases other devices sharing the same DNS server would have the problem too though. If this is the case you might need to wait until the new DNS settings are sufficiently propagated through the internet, which might take in the worst case a few days but usually only hours.

Comment: Thanks for posting a solution. The IP is not likely a problem because using another device on the same network, the website works. Also the ip isn't static. There's no settings in the host file that relate to ip addresses or re direction. I guess the only thing I can wait for is the proper propagation